# How to interpret the given ACF and PACF graph?

Tags: time-series, acf-pacf

[image]

So,I am working with a time series data which has a Hurst exponent of 0.53 indicating a persistent time series. I made the data stationary by differencing once and both ADF and KPSS tests corroborated that.I am trying to model ARIMA on the given data and the ACF plot looks like the image attached.I am unable to interpret the same and figure out the p,q values of the AR and MA processes.Has the plot got anything to do with the persistent nature of the series? Some intuition and direction would be highly appreciated. Thank you.